# How can I use Laravel Sanctum and Passport in the same app?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in a situation where I want to install Passport and Sanctum into the same application due to them serving out the same data onto multiple platforms.

I could just use Passport for everything but Sanctum comes with some quality of life for development.

The issue I'm coming across is both the Sanctum `HasApiTokens` and Passport `HasApiTokens` traits both contain the same function names so you get a conflict.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens as SanctumApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, SanctumApiTokens; // Conflicts here

    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why do u need this ? one model 2 `token` doesn't make sense

Comment: yes. how would I go about installing sanctum and passport into one application?

Comment: I have a Laravel application running in production that uses Passport. But now I want to migrate to Sanctum. So I need both. Is this not possible? Should I just stay with Passport?